# different app logo for different languages

Tags: windows-8, internationalization, app-store

Can someone tell me if it is possible to set different logos in a Win 8 for different languages?

If yes --> how?

I need to internationalize a win 8 app, but i can set this images just in the app manifest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have not tried it... But...

In your app layout, have different folders under images (or assets) for each language. When pointing the manifest to an image, do so w/o the language.

For example:
assets\en-US\Logo.png
assets\fr-fr\Logo.png

And in the Manifest:
assets/Logo.png

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh831183.aspx